# TypeError: fields.forEach is not a function antd form.setFields(fields)

Tags: forms, antd

This, not antd latest form version I think this old version antd form fields

```
let details ={
                current_start_time: {
                  value: current_start_time,
                  errors: [],
                },
                current_end_time: {
                  value: current_end_time,
                  errors: [],
                },
              }
              this.formRef.current.setFields({
                details
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically set errors in the particular fields or another field use this method.

```
let details = [
                {
                  name: current_start_time,
                  errors: [],
                }, {
                  name: current_end_time,
                  errors: [],
                }]
              this.formRef.current.setFields(details);
```

Comment: Maybe add a mention in the description before the code that you're setting an array and not an object. It's easy to miss. Also, name should be a string. Also, this didn't work for me.